# how to make nestle looping in mustacle tag

Tags: mustache

can any body help me, i would like to looping tag in mustacle but in that looping there is looping also, nestle looping
here is my code

```
        <tbody>
            {{#table_detail}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{account_no}}</td>
                <td>{{account_name}}</td>
                {{#period}}
                    <td style="text-align:right;">{{period}}</td>
                {{/period}}
            </tr>
            {{/table_detail}}
        </tbody>
```

and this is result

```
6020    operating cost          August_2020 September_2020
9000    current year earning    August_2020 September_2020
6000    salary expences         August_2020 September_2020
9999    Net income
```

and this is my expectation

```
6020    operating cost          IDR 500.000 0
9000    current year earning    IDR -500.000    0
6000    salary expences         0   IDR 2.500.000
9999    Net income
```

this is my period array

```
[
    {
        "bulan": "August_2020"
    },
    {
        "bulan": "September_2020"
    }
]
```

and this is my table_period array

```
[
    {
        "account_no": 6020,
        "account_name": "operating cost",
        "August_2020": "IDR 500.000",
        "September_2020": 0
    },
    {
        "account_no": 9000,
        "account_name": "current year earning",
        "August_2020": "IDR -500.000",
        "September_2020": 0
    },
    {
        "account_no": 6000,
        "account_name": "salary expences",
        "August_2020": 0,
        "September_2020": "IDR 2.500.000"
    }
]
```

i want get the value of the month, but what i got is the month name,

thank before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i did not using mustache but using pure htlm in my view blade
this is my view blade, with special looping

```
       <tbody>
        @foreach($detail as $each)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$each['account_no']}}</td> 
            <td>{{$each['account_name']}}</td> 
            @foreach ($month_name as $month )
                <td style="text-align:right;">{{$each[$month]}}</td>
            @endforeach 
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

this will return month name as column like pivot in excel